# How to build a same form for multiple pages in Symfony 5?

Tags: forms, symfony

I wanted to display a same form in different pages in Symfony 5. There is a way to do that without create the same form in each controller action ?

Comment: "Symfony recommends to put as little logic as possible in controllers. That’s why it’s better to move complex forms to dedicated classes instead of defining them in controller actions."  https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course, you can.

Please take a look at the [Creating Form Classes](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes) section in Symfony's docs.

Basically you need to create a class implementing `FormTypeInterface`, or to make it even simpler use `AbstractType` class, which implements most of the required stuff. Then you only need to implement `buildForm` method, which is almost the same, what you currently probably write in your controllers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jakub, but sadly I didn't explain very well I guess. I already make an AbstractType but my form have to be in each pages in my website (it's a newsletter form). So now, if I want to have my form in each pages, I have to do the same code in each controllers, and that's why I'm here, I want to know if there is a way to make my form only one time for each controllers, each pages ?

Comment: Oh, I get it. Then you have at least two options. The first one is to create a Twig Extension, which would create a form instance. The other one is to create a controller for this form and then render it in your layout template as an embedded controller.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old question but in my opinion the best way to do this is missing. Just in case anyone is looking for the same thing:

1. Create a Event Subscriber that subscribes to the `KernelEvents::CONTROLLER` kernel event.
2. Add the form as a twig global in the event subscriber function
3. Reference the form in your template

You shouldn't have to add the subscriber as a service as long as autowire is enabled (default).

Below is a example that allows you to specify which controllers the form will load on (optional).

```
<?php

namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use App\Controller\YourController1;
use App\Controller\YourController2;
use App\Controller\YourController3;
use App\Form\YourForm;
use Twig\Environment;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Flash\FlashBagInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class YourFormSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    protected Environment $environment;
    protected FormFactoryInterface $formFactory;
    protected Request $request;
    protected FlashBagInterface $flashBag;

    public function __construct(
        Environment $environment,
        FormFactoryInterface $formFactory,
        RequestStack $requestStack
    ){
        $this->environment = $environment;
        $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
        $this->request = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
        $this->flashBag = $this->request->getSession()->getFlashBag();
    }
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::CONTROLLER => 'onKernelController',
        ];
    }

    public function onKernelController(ControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $controller = $event->getController();

        // when a controller class defines multiple action methods, the controller
        // is returned as [$controllerInstance, 'methodName']
        if (is_array($controller)) {
            $controller = $controller[0];
        }
        //only load your form for specific controllers (optional)
        if ($controller instanceof YourController1 ||
            $controller instanceof YourController2 ||
            $controller instanceof YourController3
        ) {
            //handle your form submit and add your form as a twig global variable
            $yourForm = $this->formFactory->create(YourForm::class, null, []);
            $yourForm->handleRequest($this->request);
            if ($yourForm->isSubmitted() && $yourForm->isValid())
            {
                $this->flashBag->add('success', 'Your form has been submitted!');
            }
            $this->environment->addGlobal('yourForm', $yourForm->createView());
        }
    }
}
```

Next display your form in a template like you normally would:

```
{{ form_start(yourForm) }}
{# form fields #}
{{ form_end(yourForm) }}
```

To have the form available to any template on ALL CONTROLLERS simply change the onKernelController method to the one below:

```
public function onKernelController(ControllerEvent $event)
{
    $controller = $event->getController();

    // when a controller class defines multiple action methods, the controller
    // is returned as [$controllerInstance, 'methodName']
    if (is_array($controller)) {
        $controller = $controller[0];
    }
    //handle your form submit and add your form as a twig global variable
    $yourForm = $this->formFactory->create(YourForm::class, null, []);
    $yourForm->handleRequest($this->request);
    if ($yourForm->isSubmitted() && $yourForm->isValid())
    {
        $this->flashBag->add('success', 'Your form has been submitted!');
    }
    $this->environment->addGlobal('yourForm', $yourForm->createView());
}
```